# Logstash - Substring from CSV column

Tags: csv, filter, elasticsearch, substring, logstash

I want to import many informations from a CSV file to Elastic Search.
My issue is I don't how can I use a equivalent of substring to select information into a CSV column.

In my case I have a field date (YYYYMMDD) and I want to have (YYYY-MM-DD).

I use filter, mutate, gsub like:

```
filter 
{
  mutate 
  {
    gsub => ["date", "[0123456789][0123456789][0123456789][0123456789][0123456789][0123456789][0123456789][0123456789]", "[0123456789][0123456789][0123456789][0123456789]-[0123456789][0123456789]-[0123456789][0123456789]"]
  }
}
```

But my result is false.
I can indentified my string but I don't how can I extract part of this.

My target it's to have something like:

```
gsub => ["date", "[0123456789][0123456789][0123456789][0123456789][0123456789][0123456789][0123456789][0123456789]","%{date}(0..3}-%{date}(4..5)-%{date}"(6..7)]
```

%{date}(0..3} : select from the first to the 4 characters of csv columns date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can use a regexp range to match a sequence, so rather than [0123456789], you can do [0-9].  If you know there will be 4 numbers, you can do [0-9]{4}.

Second, you want to "capture" parts of your input string and reorder them in the output.  For that, you need capture groups:

```
([0-9]{4})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})
```

where parens define the groups.  Then you can reference those on the right side of your gsub:

```
\1-\2-\3
```

\1 is the first capture group, etc.

You might also consider getting these three fields when you do the grok{}, and then putting them together again later (perhaps with add_field).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ruby` plugin to do conversion. As you say, you will have a `date` field. So, we can use it directly in `ruby`

```
filter {
    ruby {
        code => "
                date = Time.strptime(event['date'],'%Y%m%d')
                event['date_new'] = date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
        "
    }
}
```

The `date_new` field is the format you want.